# Index best performance tuning

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables `Customer` and `Customerkpi`

In both tables we have the column `Customer_id` which should contain unique values.

`Customer_id` in `Customerkpi` is a foreign key of the `Customer_id` of the table `Customer` which is the primary key.

I need to create indexes on `customerkpi` in the best way.

Should I create a primary key on `Customer_id` and mentioned also the foreign key in this way it creates automatically a clustered index, or should I just declare it as a foreign key and then I create a cluster unique index on `Customer_id`.

which solution give the best performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I create a primary key on Customer_id and mentioned also the
>   foreign key in this way it creates automatically a clustered index, or
>   should I just declare it as a foreign key and then I create a cluster
>   unique index on Customer_id.

The physical indexes (clustered and unique) will be identical in both cases so it makes no difference from a performance perspective whether the index also supports the primary key constraint.  I would personally use a clustered primary key index since relational tables should have a primary key and add the foreign key too.